# Finding the item with the minimal value in a sequence

Tags: python, beginner, algorithm, python-3.x, reinventing-the-wheel

This is an algorithm to find the item with the minimal value in a sequence. I've written a function called **minimal** to implement this algorithm.

Here is my script:

```
def minimal(*args):
    """Returns the item with the minimal value in a sequence. """
    if len(args) == 1:
        sequence = args[0]
    else:    
        sequence = args

    index = 0
    successor = index + 1

    while successor < len(sequence):
        if sequence[index] > sequence[successor]:
            index = successor 
        successor += 1

    return sequence[index]
```

Comment: What's wrong with `min`? Or did you do it for the fun of it? In that case add the tag [tag:reinventing-the-wheel]

Comment: Oh! I didn't know of that tag. I know  `min`, I'm just practicing for fun!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Redundant use of indexing

Since you only need value, not index, you could store current minimal value instead of its index. This would allow for `for` loop, like

```
for item in sequence:
    if item < current_minimum:
        current_minimum = item
```

You both ditch overhead for array access, for tracking the index and - most important - code looks cleaner. (although that's subjective)

#### No support for generators

Generators provide items one at a time, instead of wasting memory on all of them at once. Your code would force generation of all items *before* first of them is processed. This is not really good.

Well, if you don't use indexing then you don't need `len` and generators would work just fine, your `if len(args) == 1:` clause is good in this regard.

#### Confusing behaviour with single argument

However, special treatment for a lone argument is not obvious from signature, that's not really good. If one does not know about this behaviour, one can easily use stuff like `min_element = minimal(*some_list)` which would *generally* work but will do an unexpected thing if `some_list` had only one element.

Yes, it seems extremely useful, but also confusing. Maybe limiting to one argument only and expecting users to do stuff like `minimal((1,2))`? I'm really not sure. It seems useful enough that built-in `min` works like that, but generally speaking decisions like this should not be taken lightly.

Also, take a closer look at what [`min`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) does - there's also an option of using a key function and providing default value.

Comment: Thank you! I've, just, implemented that! It's much better.

Comment: It's also important to set current_minimum to sequence[0], and you can also splice the list to ignore the first element on the first recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Here are five different ways to find the min

```
from functools import reduce

#Min
def find_min1(iterable_obj):
    return min(iterable_obj)

#Iteration
def find_min2(iterable_obj):
    current_minimum = iterable_obj[0]
    for item in iterable_obj[1:]:
        if item < current_minimum:
            current_minimum = item
    return current_minimum

#Reduce
def find_min3(iterable_obj):
    return reduce(lambda x, y: x if x<y else y, iterable_obj)

#Sorted
def find_min4(iterable_obj):
    return sorted(iterable_obj)[0]

#Recursion
def find_min5(iterable_obj):
    if(len(iterable_obj) == 1):
        return iterable_obj[0]
    else:
        return min(iterable_obj[0],find_min4(iterable_obj[1:]))
```

Listen in approximate speed order based on profiling by `cProfile` Recursion crashed before list size 10,000. Build in was usually fastest, but all were within ~.001 seconds except for recursion which quickly tanked due to system overhead function calls.

Comment: In resursive solution, you are calling `find_min4` - `sorted` one. Is it a typo? (also, there are actually 2 ways to do it recursively - right fold and left fold - but both are not really suitable for Python)